# Syntax error in my excel VBA -- specifically re: a worksheet function in R1C1 form

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with a VBA script that I am writing to make the month end analysis of order book movements for a business where I work easier to carry out.

(I am a total a newbie, and have started learning VBA using Mr Walkenbach's 'VBA for Dummies' just to achieve this very task that I am now stuck on!)

This VBA script is part of a suite of other VBA scripts I have written to make the task easier - this is the only one I am stuck on.

I was previously carrying out this analysis using excel and just copy/pasting formulas then changing incorrect references etc to different workbooks month on month - I used the formulas from these workbooks as the basis for my VBA scripts so I know they do work in excel.  I suspect there are much easier/less complex ways of achieving the same thing, but this is the limit of my ability!

The syntax error happens with the worksheet function enclosed in ** below:

```
  Sub Despatches_Matrix()
 '
 ' Despatches_Matrix Macro
 '
 Dim LastRow As Long, n As Long, LastCol As Long
 Dim RowVar As Integer
 Dim ColVar As Integer

Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "Despatches"
Sheets("Difference").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Despatches").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Rows("3:3").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Despatches").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Despatches").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "C3:C1000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Despatches").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A3:Bz1000")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
    End With

LastRow = Range("c1000").End(xlUp).Row
For n = LastRow To 3 Step -1
If Cells(n, 3).Value = 0 Then Cells(n, 3).EntireRow.Delete

Next n

LastCol = Range("Bz2").End(xlToLeft).Column - 7

'MsgBox (LastCol)

RowVar = 3

Do While Range("A" & RowVar) <> Empty

    Range("D" & RowVar).Formula = "=ROUND(IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A" & RowVar & ",OpeningOrderBookPivot!$A$3:$B$1000,2,FALSE)),0,IF(AND(VLOOKUP(A" & RowVar & ",OpeningOrderBookPivot!$A$3:$B$1000,2,FALSE)>0,VLOOKUP(A" & RowVar & ",OpeningOrderBookPivot!$A$3:$B$41000,2,FALSE)>=-C" & RowVar & "),C" & RowVar & ",IF(AND(VLOOKUP(A" & RowVar & ",OpeningOrderBookPivot!$A$3:$B$1000,2,FALSE)>0,VLOOKUP(A" & RowVar & ",OpeningOrderBookPivot!$A$3:$B$1000,2,FALSE)<-C" & RowVar & "),-VLOOKUP(A" & RowVar & ",OpeningOrderBookPivot!$A$3:$B$1000,2,FALSE),(0)))),0)"

    Range("E" & RowVar).Formula = "=ROUND(IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A" & RowVar & ",OpeningOrderBookPivot!$A$3:$B$1000,3,FALSE)),C" & RowVar & ",IF(AND(C" & RowVar & "<D" & RowVar & ",VLOOKUP(Despatches!A" & RowVar & ",OpeningOrderBookPivot!$A$3:$C$1000,3,FALSE)>0,VLOOKUP(A" & RowVar & ",OpeningOrderBookPivot!$A$3:$C$1000,3,FALSE)>=-(Despatches!C" & RowVar & "-Despatches!D" & RowVar & ")),C" & RowVar & "-D" & RowVar & ",IF(AND(C" & RowVar & "<D" & RowVar & ",VLOOKUP(Despatches!A" & RowVar & ",OpeningOrderBookPivot!$A$3:$C$1000,3,FALSE)>0,VLOOKUP(A" & RowVar & ",OpeningOrderBookPivot!$A$3:$C$1000,3,FALSE)<-(Despatches!C" & RowVar & "-Despatches!D" & RowVar & ")),-VLOOKUP(A" & RowVar & ",OpeningOrderBookPivot!$A$3:$C$1000,3,FALSE),0))),0)"


        ColVar = 6

        Do While ActiveSheet.Cells(2, ColVar) <> Empty

        **Cells(RowVar, ColVar).FormulaR1C1 = "=ROUND(IF(AND(-R" & RowVar & "C3>-SUM(R" & RowVar & "C4:R" & RowVar & "C" & ColVar -1 & "),VLOOKUP(R" & RowVar & "C1,Difference!R" & RowVar & "C1:R1000C" & ColVar & ",(MATCH(R2C" & ColVar & ",Difference!R2,0)),FALSE)>0,VLOOKUP(R" & RowVar & "C1,Difference!R" & RowVar & "C1:R1000C" & ColVar & ",(MATCH(R2C" & ColVar & ",Difference!R2,0)),FALSE)>=-(Despatches!R" & RowVar & "C3-(SUM(R" & RowVar & "C4:R" & RowVar & "C" & ColVar - 1 & ")))),R" & RowVar & "C3-SUM(R" & RowVar & "C4:R" & RowVar & "C" & ColVar & " -1),IF(AND(-R" & RowVar & "C3>-SUM(R" & RowVar & "C4,R" & RowVar & ":C" & ColVar & " -1),VLOOKUP(R" & RowVar & ",Difference!R" & RowVar & "C1:R1000C" & ColVar & ",(Match(R2C" & ColVar & ",Difference!R2,0)),False)>0,-VLOOKUP(R" & RowVar & "C1,Difference!R" & RowVar & "C1:R1000C" & ColVar & ",(MATCH(R2C" & ColVar & ",Difference!R2,0)),False) _
        <-(Despatches!R" & RowVar & "C3-(Sum(R" & RowVar & "C4,R" & RowVar & "C" & ColVar -1 & ")))),-VLOOKUP(R" & RowVar & "C1,Difference!R" & RowVar & "C1:R1000C" & ColVar & ",(Match(R2C" & ColVar & ",Difference!R2,0)),False),IF(VLOOKUP(Despatches!R" & RowVar & "C1,Difference!R" & RowVar & "C1:R1000C" & ColVar & ",(MATCH(R2C" & ColVar &  ",Difference!R2,0)),False)=0,0,0))),0)"**

ColVar = ColVar + 1


            Loop


    RowVar = RowVar + 1


Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a really long piece of code. Please look at the principles of Minimal, Complete and Verifiable: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and try to improve your question. That makes it easier for us to provide you with answers and help. Also what exactly is the error?

Comment: Also in this case I think it might be better to opt for an all VBA solution, instead of trying to program workbook functions. Maybe you can share an example of your excel file with us, and the calculations that need to be performed.

Comment: Hi Luuklag, thank you for looking into my problem - I totally understand your MCV point, I am a bit of a victim of being new to this and not really able to take it to pieces and re-start it.  The best way I could work out how to do it is as I have, take worksheet functions, convert them and then surround by VBA to 'make it happen, as it were.

Comment: The error is simply:  Compile error:  Syntax error.  Unfortunately I cannot include the work sheets due to commercially sensitive nature of the contents.  I will have a look at @Jeeped's solution below to see if this works.  Thanks you for taking the time to review and respond to my question.

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum the code line you have marked with two asterisks should end with `)" & _` not `) _` and the beginning of the next line should be `"<-(` not `<-(`.

Also all of your `RowVar` vars can be removed. In xlR1C1, if you are on the same row then `RC3` and `R" & RowVar & "C3` mean the same thing. It's like saying (when on row 5) C5 and C$5 and it should make no difference for your formula because you are putting then on the same row.

```
With ActiveSheet    'this should be better like Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Do While .Cells(2, ColVar) <> Empty
        .Cells(RowVar, ColVar).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=ROUND(IF(AND(-RC3>-SUM(RC4:RC" & ColVar - 1 & "),VLOOKUP(RC1,Difference!RC1:R1000C" & ColVar & ",(MATCH(R2C" & ColVar & ",Difference!R2,0)),FALSE)>0,VLOOKUP(RC1,Difference!RC1:R1000C" & ColVar & ",(MATCH(R2C" & ColVar & ",Difference!R2,0)),FALSE)>=-(Despatches!RC3-(SUM(RC4:RC" & ColVar - 1 & "))))" & _
             ",RC3-SUM(RC4:RC" & ColVar & " -1),IF(AND(-RC3>-SUM(RC4,R" & RowVar & ":C" & ColVar & " -1),VLOOKUP(R" & RowVar & ",Difference!RC1:R1000C" & ColVar & ",(Match(R2C" & ColVar & ",Difference!R2,0)),False)>0,-VLOOKUP(RC1,Difference!RC1:R1000C" & ColVar & ",(MATCH(R2C" & ColVar & ",Difference!R2,0)),False)" & _
             "<-(Despatches!RC3-(Sum(RC4,RC" & ColVar - 1 & ")))),-VLOOKUP(RC1,Difference!RC1:R1000C" & ColVar & ",(Match(R2C" & ColVar & ",Difference!R2,0)),False),IF(VLOOKUP(Despatches!RC1,Difference!RC1:R1000C" & ColVar & ",(MATCH(R2C" & ColVar & ",Difference!R2,0)),False)=0,0,0))),0)"

        ColVar = ColVar + 1
    Loop
End With
```

Now that formula-as-a-string does compile but I cannot attest to its validity on a worksheet. One method I have used for complicated formulas is to use the `'` [Range.PrefixCharacter property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.prefixcharacter.aspx) to put the formula into the worksheet as a string.

```
.Cells(RowVar, ColVar).FormulaR1C1 = "'=ROUND(IF(AND(-R...
```

Once the routine has run through, go back to the worksheet and try and remove the `'` to see if it is a valid formula and if it is returning the correct result.

Comment: Thank you Jeeped, I have not the time to run this through right now (am busy on other things at work :-(  but I will put the changes through that you suggest when I get chance and let you know the results.

Comment: Jeeped, you were absolutely right - it was as simple as your first point regarding the correct ending of the lines of code.  A bit of tinkering then to get the formula doing exactly what I need it to do and it is complete!   Thanks so much, you have saved me time and meant that the 3-4 days of putting this suite of macros together has not been in vain!